# Async process not switching a boolean trigger

Tags: python, opencv, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have the following steps I need to follow:

1 - I need to start a camera instance on OpenCV

2 - I need to send the camera's data to some outside source every 2 seconds, but the video feed obviously cannot stop in the meantime

So I made two main async functions: "flip_trigger", which switches a boolean variable every 2 seconds, and "camera_feed", which also consumes the same "send_image" trigger that s switched by "flip_trigger". The two must run at the same time.

```
send_image = False



async def flip_trigger():
    global send_image
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        send_image = not send_image
        print("Awaiting image")

async def camera_feed():
    global send_image
    face_names = []
    face_usernames = []
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        if(send_image):
            ret, frame = video_capture.read()
            #(...) some other code
        else:
            ret, frame = video_capture.read()
            cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
            continue
        #(...) some other code
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
        video_capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break


async def start_camera():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(flip_trigger())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(camera_feed())
    await asyncio.wait({task1, task2}, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED) 


asyncio.run(start_camera())
```

The problem is: while debugging the code on VSCode, it seemingly never gets past the "await asyncio.sleep(2)" line, and if I remove the "await" parameter, the code seems to get stuck inside the "flip_trigger" function.

How do I make these functions work at the same time, and make "camera_feed" capture the "send_image" boolean switches in real time?

Comment: the real problem you'll get isn't what's been described already, but that VideoCapture.read() will block and you can't do anything about that. you **have to** run that in a proper thread (**not** multiprocessing, a _thread_) if you want other code to continue executing while the read() blocks for the next frame -- I haven't even addressed that you use OpenCV's imshow and waitKey... that **does not mix at all** with async. you must use a proper GUI toolkit that works with python's async stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `await` asyncio tries to continue other tasks in the loop.
Imagine when `await` especially in combination with `asyncio.sleep` is called it pauses the execution and it hops to another `await` section region where it can continue.
There **normal python code is executed sequentially until the next await is reached**.

Your `camera_feed` has no `await`, that means it will continuously loop forever/until the break.
It won't go back to `flip_trigger`.

You can use `asyncio.sleep(0)` to enable a ping pong between both functions.